# Ubuntu - Install Non-Latest Package as a Dependency

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

I'm trying to build a debian package using FPM. This package, we'll call it Package A, has a custom-built dependency, Package B. Let's say Package A.1 depends on Package B.1. If B.2 is added to the repository, Package A.1 will fail to install ("Unmet dependencies"), since the OS wants to install B.2.

Is there a way to force Ubuntu to install package B.1 when package A.1 is installed, even though B.2 exists on the repo?

Background: Package A is really our product, which is a ruby on rails application. Package B is a specific version of Ruby, since the version of Ruby on Ubuntu tends to lag behind. If we specify an exact version of the ruby package to be installed along with our software, it works great...until a we build a newer version of ruby and place it on the repo. Getting a too-new version of Ruby installed will break the application.